# How to retrieve method arguments of a decorated python method

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following code in python2.7 where the decorator is a third party code and shall not be changed:

```
# tasks.py
def test(val):
    print val

@app.task
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

#main.py:
import mypackage.tasks as tasks
for method in tasks.__dict__.values():
    if hasattr(method, '_decorated') and method._decorated:
        print method.name.split('.')[-1]
        ### here I want to get the method arguments
```

The problem is that I cannot get the method arguments of a decorated method.
I've already tried:

```
inspect.getargspec(method)
#and
tasks.test.func_code.co_varnames
```

they do not work for decorated methods.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this python-flask?

Comment: No. It's celery tasks.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?